# eBay API GetCategory using CategoryName

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-lms

Does ebay provide `Category` using `CategoryName`? I can get the `Category` using `categoryid`, but I want to get it using `CategoryName`

Something similar to the following URL, when I call an ebay api with category name it should give me the response of category.

http://open.api.ebay.com/Shopping?callname=GetCategoryInfo&appid=YourAppiD&siteid=3&**CategoryName=Antiques**&version=729

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this functionality isn't provided by eBay is: 1) it's not very specific, whereas a CategoryID is very specific; 2) there are many duplicate category names, like "Other", or time periods (1900-1949) that could refer to comic, coins, stamps, etc.